# The difference between hydroxide and oxyhydroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I cant discern these two terminologies. Would someone be very kind to help me on it?

I think hydroxide mean M(OH)x where M is a metal ion, while oxyhydroxide means something like MO(OH). Is that right? Oxyhydroxide equals to oxide-hydroxide.

Comment: You may see this:-http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44159/what-is-the-structural-difference-between-mnooh-and-mnooh2

Comment: Thanks! Then I have a further question, is the OH in oxyhydroxide anion or it is charge balance like the OH in organics? I ask this because in the Chinese nomenclature of NiO(OH), they tend to the second one which means that the OH and NiO(I think it is the Ni in NiO) are bonding together by covalent bond.

Comment: In both the cases, the -OH group is covalently bonded to  manganese. So, I think in case of nickel  also the -OH group is covalently bonded. I am not too sure about it but don't worry. I will search  about it and tell you the answer.

Comment: Actually NiOOH follow a solid state chemistry. In page 3 of [this link](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja068433a), it says that NiOOH  has various type of forms like beta-, gamma- etc. Here, the nickel oxide layer is stacked one above the other to form a lattice. But conventionally, NiOOH should be said nickel (III )oxyhydroxide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have correct idea.

Oxyhydroxide is any mixed oxide and hydroxide. For example [Iron(III) oxide-hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_oxide-hydroxide)

While in [hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxide) hydrogen and oxygen atom are joined with covalent bond.

Comment: Thanks Freddy! Then I have a further question, is the OH in oxyhydroxide anion or it is charge balance like the OH in organics? I ask this because in the Chinese nomenclature of  NiO(OH), they tend to the second one which means that the OH and NiO(I think it is the Ni in NiO) are bonding together by covalent bond.

Answer (score 1):

To go back to the question given in the title, the difference between oxides and hydroxides is simply water $\ce{H2O}$.

Let's take the example of iron $\ce{Fe(III)}$. Its hydroxide is $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$. Its main oxyhydroxide is $\ce{FeOOH}$. And this oxyhydroxide is obtained by removing one water molecule from $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ according to : $$\ce{Fe(OH)3 -> FeOOH + H2O}$$

Answer (score -4):

Mate oxyhydride is -OH whereas hydroxide is HO+. Only difference is charge. I have heard somewhere that both can be used in writing chemical equations. However, this is wrong. You can use both OH and HO to signify presence of hydroxide. But oxyhydride is -OH whereas hydroxide is HO+. Hydroxide is an organic covalent bond. Oxyhydride is a mixed bond.

Comment: " oxyhydride is -OH whereas hydroxide is HO+" Reference, please

Comment: @Ian Bush. HO+ is a theoretical concept that does not exist in practice in the lab. OH- does exist. It is the anion hydroxide. This anion is part of metallic hydroxides. For example, OH- is contained in the famous sodium hydroxide $\ce{NaOH}$, which is one of the most important hydroxides in the world.

Comment: @Maurice I understand that entirely. But this answer to the question I found so ... surprising ...  I wanted to find where this, errr, assertion was derived from

Comment: @Ian Bush. Which assertion do you find surprising ?

Comment: @Maurice "oxyhydride is -OH whereas hydroxide is HO+" Hydroxide has never been OH+ in any of the 35 years since I got my chemistry degree, and nor has -OH been oxyhydride ( or oxyhydroxide for that matter ). I want to find out where this is being stated to be the case.

Comment: @Ian Bush this is not my words. I re checked and after consulting my science textbook and a quick search on Google I found this in Quora as well. It could completely be an error in my old textbook and you cannot trust Quora. Anyways, thanks a lot for correcting me.

Comment: Really sorry if I made a mistake. I'm always learning. Thank you for this information

Comment: The thing is I too thought how this happened. I recently came here from Quora. This is carry wierd. I just posted the thing I read on Quora and reddit.

Comment: @Maurice Where have I said that? I am just quoting the original poster. I am making no such claims.

Comment: True. You have not claimed that. I sincerely apologise for any misunderstanding I caused. You merely pointed out my mistake.

Comment: @Ian Bush. The word "oxyhydride" does not describe the ion OH−
This ion is called "hydroxide". Hydroxyde is the typical ion present in basic solutions in water. Hydroxyde is the anion OH−. It is not a cation.
 It is produced by autoprotolysis in water, and by dissolving metallic hydroxides in water. It is not HO+.
 !

Comment: @Maurice Last thing I will say. Please read what I said. I never claimed hydroxide is OH+. I never claimed oxyhydride is OH-. Note the inverted commas around my original comment. This implies I am quoting the above answer - it is *not* my own text, it is copy and pasted from the answer above it. I then ask for a reference to back up the assertion that I have quoted. Via this mechanism I am calling into question that very assertion - because IMO it is mistaken, but I want to give the person answering an opportunity to either correct or clarify themselves.

Comment: @Ian Bush. Thank you for your message. And sorry ! I had not really understood the meaning of the inverted commas around your original comment. .

Comment: @Maurice No problem - the internet is not always the easiest way to convey the intention behind your text, and unfortunately misunderstanding is rife. Glad we have it sorted it out.